# Inject html between Marionette ItemViews inside a CollectionView

Tags: marionette, backbone-views, collectionview

I have a collection view (`MyCollView` below), and want to (conditionally) inject html between the different itemViews (`MyItemView` below) **without modifying `MyItemView`**. I know there are lots of different options that CollectionViews can have, but didn't see anything for this particular use.

More specifics: I want to inject a `<br>` tag after each MyItemView in the `MyCollView` as long as the instance of `MyItemView` is not the last in the collection.
Here's my desired output for what my collection view would render:

```
<div>name1</div>
<br>
<div>name2</div>
<br>
<div>name3</div>
```

Here's my code:

```
MyItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: _.template('<div><%= name %></div>')
});

MyCollView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    childView: MyItemView
    //ideally, I would like to provide some other property to accomplish my goal here, like...
    //separatorHtml: '<br>'
});

var myColl = new Backbone.Collection([
    {name: 'name1'},
    {name: 'name2'},
    {name: 'name3'}
]);

thisCollView = new MyCollView({
    collection: myColl
});

thisCollView.render();
```

My thoughts now are to extend the `MyItemView` into `MyModifiedItemView` and put in this optional `<br>` tag, but I didn't know if there was more of a "marionette-y" way to do it. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Override [attachHtml](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.0/marionette.collectionview.html#collectionviews-attachhtml)?

Comment: Any luck finding a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you can use Marionette view events to hook an html element to that view's template. That's ok, if the element you want to attach will exists *inside* that view's `el`. Your case is a bit tricky because, you want to add a `<br/>` *outside* each item view. (If you want to know exactly why this is an issue, ask me in the comments).Instead, what we'll do is listen in the parent CollectionView to when a child is added.

You, also want the `<br>` element you add to be conditional. We can take advantage of an internal property of Marionette views, `view._index`, along with the reference to the collection Backbone adds to each model, to test whether the current item view rendered is the last one.

Putting it all together all you have to do is add this property to `MyCollView`:

```
onAddChild : function (childview) {
    if (this.collection.length !== childview._index + 1)
        childview.$el.after('<br/>');
}
```

which checks if the child view that was just added is the last view in the collection, or not.

Comment: When `onAddChild` is called, the child view may not yet be attached to the DOM. So trying to add elements after the root element of the view does nothing if you use jQuery or you get an error if you use DOM methods directly (e.g. ` childview.el.insertAdjacentHTML("afterEnd", html);`).